# Setting up a video view

Tags: android, android-videoview

I added the following code to my app to add a video view which is linked to a video in my raw folder but I'm getting an error on 
VideoView saying that `VideoView cannot be resolved or is not a field`I have included all the relevant imports.Is the an error somewhere in my syntax?

```
VideoView StudentLife = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.learningatgmi);

        videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoview.start();
```

My xml layout for videoview is as follows:

```
<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp" />
```

Comment: is it compile time error on run time? can you show the xml layout file?

Comment: It's a compile time error.I just added the xml layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you variable name is `StudentLife`

```
VideoView StudentLife = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
```

and you are calling other mehtod's on `videoview` which is undefined variable..

So following code:

```
        videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoview.start();
```

should be:

```
        StudentLife.setVideoURI(uri);
        StudentLife.start();
```

EDIT1:

As per you xml the line to get the instance of video view should be following

```
VideoView StudentLife = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
```

Full working code should be as following:

```
VideoView StudentLife = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.learningatgmi);
StudentLife.setVideoURI(uri);
StudentLife.start();
```

On the side not; you should not use the class name as the variable name... also in java first character of variable should not be capital... So let use 'videoView' as the variable name.. So now following should be the working code with right kind of variable name..

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.learningatgmi);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.start();
```

Comment: Ok actually myclass name is StudentLife.Is this still the correct definition or should I create a variable? Thanks

Comment: you should create a variable with some other name.. `viewView` could be used in place of `StudentLife` in the code that I posted in answer....

Comment: Thanks a lot I just realized the mistake I was making with the R.id.

Answer (score 1):

The id of your `VideoView` is `videoView1`. So you should get a reference to the `VideoView` object from the view hierarchy using `R.id.videoView1`:

```
 VideoView StudentLife = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.learningatgmi);
 StudentLife.setVideoURI(uri);
 StudentLife.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

My code works ::

```
mc = new MediaController(this);
vd.setMediaController(mc);
vd.setVideoURI(intentUri);
vd.start();
setContentView(vd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you use this code,

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.learningatgmi);
StudentLife.setVideoURI(uri);
```

It passes URI as null so it shows you error
So instead of that you cant use following code.

```
StudentLife=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoplayer);
StudentLife.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" +getPackageName()+ "/" +R.raw.sample));
StudentLife.requestFocus();
StudentLife.start();
```

Instead of Parsing URI before setting, it will be better if you pass it during setting it.

Comment: If `uri` is null **as you said**, then `Uri.parse()` returns null. It will be `StudentLife.setVideoURI(null)' in second case also.

Comment: I had same problem earlier, when I debugged it, I came to know that it is returning null, then I tried the code given to you, it worked for me.